# Ruby on Rails - Git Branch Workflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

I know its a simple concept but just not grasping it after researching several sites.

I have a Ruby On Rails project and using git to manage the source.  I have a production ready snapshot and initialize git such that it has a master (with git init, git add -A and git commit -m).

Now I want to try out a new feature so I create a branch called 'test' with git checkout -b test

Now while in test I try out a new scaffold with rails g scaffold UserToken username:string

Scaffold created all of the ROR files and I do a rake db:migrate to update the DB.  I then go into the rails console and test out adding records to the db and then start working on updating the other generated scaffold model file.

After lunch I come back and decide I want to scrap all of this.

Questions - (after trying this out myself) is the only way to get back to master is to git add -A, git commit -m and then git checkout master ?  Do I really have to add and commit to get back to master? (this does work; however I don't think I'm grasping something basic in git that I would do a commit on something that I am going to scrap)

Next, if I do the above (again I don't think that's right) when I get back to master I do see that my scaffold files are gone as are the  migration file (which created the table) and the schema.rb reflects that the table generated while in the branch is not there.

So far so good:

HOWEVER, if I go into the actual database the table IS still there.  What basic fundamental am I missing in ROR/Git of testing something out in a branch and then abandoning it?

**UPDATE #1**

So Stash does not appear to help:
Stash does not help.

```
Steps:  
rails new test_app  
git init  
git add -A  
git commit -m 'initial commit'  

git checkout -b newfeatures  
rails g scaffold UserToken username:string coin:integer  

files get generated... 
sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3 show that there is now a table called user_tokens:  

git stash save  
git checkout master
```

Now in Master however all of the scaffold files still exist (and shouldn't)

Comment: I think you are searching for `git checkout master -f`.

Comment: @ndn I tried the git checkout master -f.  The files I creates while in my branch are still visible and shouldn't be right?

Comment: The reason that `git stash` did not work for you is because the new files were not yet under git control.  Until `git` is told about a file via `git add` it is just a file system artefact.  It is yet not part of any `git` branch and so cannot be manipulated by `git`.

Comment: Thanks James; yeah I think I've learned that the add has to happen.  I had thought that git would allow me to set a "master" and then try a bunch of stuff and simply scrap the "try" and get back to master without having to "track - add - commit" things to git that just didn't need to even be a part of the "history".

Comment: I had this problem with `git` to begin with.  I imagined that `git` was a file system somehow separate from the host's file system that contained it.  Once I realised that `git` only keeps fs states in its branches and rewrites those states to the actual fs when one switches branches things became a lot clearer and I encountered fewer surprises in behaviour.  But it took a while.

Comment: You can eliminate dead end histories in git but that involves rewriting all of the commits made in other branches as well.  It is not particularly difficult, particularly for a small project, but I have never found it worthwhile.  Your project history includes dead ends and if they are in disused branches you will never see them.  Storage space is not really a concern with git unless you have added some remarkably large files to a branch that you no longer need.  However, you do need to run `git gc` every now and then to tidy things up and reduce space consumption regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git reset --hard HEAD` deletes everything and goes back to head in your testbranch so you can easily switch back with `git checkout master`

`rake db:reset` should do the trick with your data in the DB

---

UPDATE:

If you really want to get rid of anything:

`git reset --hard && git clean -dfx
rake db:drop 
rake db:create && rake db:migrate`

Comment: See my update above, tried this as well however after the rake db:reset I still have the table in the database.

Comment: You can also `rake db:drop` and then `rake db:create && rake db:migrate`to get rid of any reminder. But in the end the additional tables or columns should not be to bad for a development environment and its enough to do this from time to time.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the trick.  I just did rails destroy scaffold, then add, commit and checkout back to master, then the drop, delete and migrate seems to have everything back to where it was Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have two questions here:

**First: How do I move between branches without commiting work in progress?**

To move between branches without having to commit your work you can use `git stash`.

```
git stash help
Usage: git stash list [<options>]
   or: git stash show [<stash>]
   or: git stash drop [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
   or: git stash ( pop | apply ) [--index] [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
   or: git stash branch <branchname> [<stash>]
   or: git stash [save [--patch] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-q|--quiet] [<message>]]
   or: git stash clear
```

Once you stash your work then you can switch between branches without problem. *Note that files that you wish to stash must first be added to a `git` branch via `git add`.  Changes to files, including creation, that have not been added to `git` are are not tracked. So they are just like any other part of the general file system and will remain visible across branches*.

**Second: Why do my database migration changes in one branch show up in another?**

Because the Database manager is not part of `git`.  Whatever DBMS you are modifying those changes are persisted through the DBMS.  If you want to keep your branch migrations separate then you need to have a separate database instance for each.

It may help if you imagine a `git` branch as a file-system template.  When you switch to another branch then that branch's template overwrites your existing file-system with whatever is under its control.  Everything else is ignored.  When you commit you are updating the template for that branch. However, all of your work is actually done in the one true file-system.

What this means that things that you do to the file-system that are outside of `git`'s control remain visible from all branches.

Comment: While the accepted answer solves the user's "how?" problem, this answers the "why?" of it.